# "No matching function for call to... unresolved overloaded function type"

Tags: c++, class, std-function, stdbind

I am trying to create a library where the user can modify the behaviour of a function on an instance-level and still manage to access the members of this instance. This post is the continuation of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206909/template-and-class-heritance) which is the continuation of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195579/class-member-function-as-function-pointer). Praetorian [suggested me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206909/template-and-class-heritance?noredirect=1#comment37378887_24206909) to use std::function/bind to do that. Unfortunately, I have two errors:

Pb #1:  **error: no matching function for call to ‘Child1::BindIt()’**

Pb #2: **error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::function’ and ‘std::_Bind_helper)(const double&), Child1*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type {aka std::_Bind(Child1*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(const double&)>}’)**

I don't understand how to solve these problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;


template<typename T,typename D> T fcn_default(const D &obj, const T &phit){
    return 3.2 + phit;
}

template<typename T> class Parent{
    public:
        Parent() {}

        T do_something(const T &phit){
            return this->fcn_ptr(phit);
        }

        std::function<T(const T&)> fcn_ptr;

};


template<typename T> class Child1 : public Parent<T>{
    public:
        Child1() {
            BindIt( &fcn_default< T , Child1<T> > ); // Pb #1: here
        }
        void BindIt(T (*ptr_in)(const T &) ){
            Parent<T>::fcn_ptr = std::bind(&ptr_in, this, std::placeholders::_1); // Pb #2: here
        }
};

template<typename T> class Child2 : public Parent<T>{
    public:
        Child2() {
            BindIt( &fcn_default< T , Child2<T> > ); // Pb #1: and here
        }
        void BindIt(T (*ptr_in)(const T &) ){
            Parent<T>::fcn_ptr = std::bind(&ptr_in, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        }

        T param2;
};


template<typename T> T fcn_mod1   (const Child1<T> &obj, const T &phit){
    return 1.2 + phit;
}
template<typename T> T fcn_mod2   (const Child2<T> &obj, const T &phit){
    return 2.2 + phit + obj.param2*0.001;
}



typedef double lrtType;

int main(){
    std::vector< Parent<lrtType> * > objects;

    Child1<lrtType> *test11 = new Child1<lrtType>();
    objects.push_back(test11);

    Child1<lrtType> *test12 = new Child1<lrtType>();
    //test12->BindIt(&fcn_mod1);
    objects.push_back(test12);

    Child2<lrtType> *test2 = new Child2<lrtType>();
    //test2->BindIt(&fcn_mod2);
    test2->param2 = 4;
    objects.push_back(test2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << objects[i]->do_something(2) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

**+++++ UPDATE +++++**

I updated the code but I still have problem #2

Pb #2: **error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::function’ and ‘std::_Bind_helper)(const double&), Child1*, const std::_Placeholder<1>&>::type {aka std::_Bind(Child1*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(const double&)>}’)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;


template<typename T,typename D> T fcn_default(const D &obj, const T &phit){
    return 3.2 + phit;
}

template<typename T> class Parent{
    public:
        Parent() {}
        virtual T do_something (const T &phit) const = 0;
};


template<typename T> class Child1 : public Parent<T>{
    public:
        Child1() {
            Child1<T>::BindIt( &fcn_default< T , Child1<T> > );
        }
        void BindIt(T (*ptr_in)(const Child1 &, const T &) ){
            fcn_ptr = std::bind(&ptr_in, this, std::placeholders::_1); // Problem here
        }
        std::function<T(const Child1 &, const T &)> fcn_ptr;
        T do_something(const T &phit) const {
            return this->fcn_ptr(*this,phit);
        }
};

template<typename T> class Child2 : public Parent<T>{
    public:
        Child2() {
            Child2<T>::BindIt( &fcn_default< T , Child2<T> > );
        }
        void BindIt(T (*ptr_in)(const Child2 &, const T &) ){
            fcn_ptr = std::bind(&ptr_in, this, std::placeholders::_1); // And here
        }
        std::function<T(const Child2 &, const T &)> fcn_ptr;

        T do_something(const T &phit) const {
            return this->fcn_ptr(*this,phit);
        }

        T param2;
};


template<typename T> T fcn_mod1   (const Child1<T> &obj, const T &phit){
    return 1.2 + phit;
}
template<typename T> T fcn_mod2   (const Child2<T> &obj, const T &phit){
    return 2.2 + phit + obj.param2*0.001;
}



typedef double lrtType;

int main(){
    std::vector< Parent<lrtType> * > objects;

    Child1<lrtType> *test11 = new Child1<lrtType>();
    objects.push_back(test11);

    Child1<lrtType> *test12 = new Child1<lrtType>();
    //test12->BindIt(&fcn_mod1);
    objects.push_back(test12);

    Child2<lrtType> *test2 = new Child2<lrtType>();
    //test2->BindIt(&fcn_mod2);
    test2->param2 = 4;
    objects.push_back(test2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << objects[i]->do_something(2) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `&fcn_default<T, Child1<T>>` is a `T(*)(const Child1<T> &, const T &)`. I don't know how you expect that to fit in a `T(*)(const T &)`.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast ... I wasn't looking in the correct direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is interested, below is a solution that works. There is however important duplication of code and I fear I can not avoid it...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;


template<typename T,typename D> T fcn_default(const D &obj, const T &phit){
    return 3.2 + phit;
}

template<typename T> class Parent{
    public:
        Parent() {}
        virtual T do_something (const T &phit) const = 0;

};

template<typename T> class Child1 : public Parent<T>{
    public:
        Child1() {
            fcn_ptr = &fcn_default< T , Child1<T> >;
        }
        std::function<T(const Child1<T> &, const T &)> fcn_ptr;

        T do_something(const T &phit) const {
            return (*this).fcn_ptr(*this,phit);
        }
};

template<typename T> class Child2 : public Parent<T>{
    public:
        Child2() {
            fcn_ptr = &fcn_default< T , Child2<T> >;
        }
        std::function<T(const Child2<T> &, const T &)> fcn_ptr;

        T do_something(const T &phit) const {
            return (*this).fcn_ptr(*this,phit);
        }

        T param2;
};



template<typename T> T fcn_mod1   (const Child1<T> &obj, const T &phit){
    return 1.2 + phit;
}
template<typename T> T fcn_mod2   (const Child2<T> &obj, const T &phit){
    return 2.2 + phit + obj.param2*0.001;
}



typedef double lrtType;

int main(){
    std::vector< Parent<lrtType> * > objects;

    Child1<lrtType> *test11 = new Child1<lrtType>();
    objects.push_back(test11);

    Child1<lrtType> *test12 = new Child1<lrtType>();
    test12->fcn_ptr = &fcn_mod1<lrtType>;
    objects.push_back(test12);

    Child2<lrtType> *test2 = new Child2<lrtType>();
    test2->fcn_ptr = &fcn_mod2<lrtType>;
    test2->param2 = 4;
    objects.push_back(test2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << objects[i]->do_something(2) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you still interested in getting the second example in your question to work?

Comment: Yes, I will learn a bit more on std::function and std::bind. I couldn't find tutorials on them only the c++ reference.